# How can I swap opposite corners on the same face of a 2x2 Rubik's cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I've been experimenting with using Y-permutations to solve the 2x2 cube as described [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Solving-a-2x2-Rubiks-Cube-Blindfolded/). I ended up with the cube solved but for a single face where the opposite corners were swapped and disoriented. I managed to solve the cube, but I wonder if there is a shorter algorithm to accomplish this task.

Comment: With one set-up move you can also try the T permutation to swap corners, and afterwards just rotate the corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rotate the face one quarter-turn, you will have a 3-cycle to solve.
That may be easier.

ADDED IN EDIT

Ouch! not a 3-cycle but a product of two 2-cycles, but still an even
permutation.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.